# Complex counting on discrete mathematic.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many bit strings contain exactly five 0s and fourteen 1s if every 0 must be
immediately followed by two 1s?

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly simple - think it through, with this hint:

What you have is five bit-triples "011" and another four 1s. How many ways can you arrange these nine "bit-sequences"?

**Hint 2**: So as I said, you must have two 1s after a zero, which means you have five bit-triples "011". Let's use a letter to replace them - "x". So you have five "x" and four "1", and you have to put them in an order. But you don't have to care about where you put the 1s, they'll fill in the holes left by the "x"s. Suppose you had two "x" and one "1". Then you could have xx1, x1x, or 1xx. As far as it matters, you're *choosing* two places to put an "x", and then the remaining place is filled by the 1.

So if you have five "x" and four "1", then how many ways can you put the five "x" into a set of nine positions? For instance, xxxxx1111, or xx1x1x1x1, or 1xx11xxx1.

Comment: They will be arrange in one way 011,011,011,011,011,1,1,1,1, since the last 4 bits sequence are 1(same) and every 0 must followed by two 1s. What you think? If I'm wrong then give a one counter example please.

Comment: What about 1,011,011,1,011,1,011,1,011?

Comment: OK, I thought that if I arrange like this then there will be some 0 lead by 1, but now I clearly understand. One more thing from your counter example, is there any different between the first 1 to the left and the second one to the right?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking, but basically, the conditions you put in the question only require that a zero have two 1s after it. It says nothing about what comes before a zero. By the time you read this, I'll have edited in an additional hint that might help further.

Answer (score 1):

How many different bit strings do you have, if you use these 9 boxes? $\boxed{011},\boxed{011},\boxed{011},\boxed{011},\boxed{011},\boxed{1},\boxed{1},\boxed{1},\boxed{1}$

Comment: 9x9=81 or 9^2=81 am I right or wrong?

Comment: Wrong. You should use permutations with repetition.

Comment: It should be 9! = 362880? How about that?

Comment: It should be 9! = 362880? But I'm confuse since 0 must be followed by two 1s and don't know how to rearrange the last four boxes, they are same.

Comment: 011 **011** 1 is the same as **011** 0111. You must use permutation with repetition. Hence the result is _9!/(5!*4!)_

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I come up with the final answer, workout by permutation with indistinguishable objects.

Answer (score 0):

Given that '0' is followed by "11",now simply append "11" right to '0' making it '**011011011011011**' .Here we have eaten up all '0's and left with 4 '1's .consider all the resultant string with a string of length 9 '**XXXXX1111**'.
Now how many Strings are there using this pattern??? just steal 2 (0/1) from this 9 length string obtained which is none but C(9,2)

Answer (score 0):

Total number of positions=19.
Every 0 must be followed by 11. Consider 011 to be a unit. So now we've to arrange five 011s and four 1s in 9 positions
This can be done in 9C5 ways